# Usar uma tag html que está em um banco MySQL em uma página

Tags: php, mysql, html5, banco-de-dados

Inseri a seguinte tag direto no banco

```
<iframe width="962" height="541" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w2Ov5jzm3j8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Mas na hora de usar ela em uma página não estou conseguindo

```
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT ofe.ofeVideo FROM tbloferta ofe WHERE ofe.ofeVideo != null";
        $query = $conn->query($sql);
        while ($row = $query->fetch_array()) {
          $ofeVideo = $row['ofeVideo'];
          echo htmlentities($ofeVideo);
        }
        ?>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ao invés de usar no comando sql `!=` para diferente, troquei para `is not` ficou assim:

```
SELECT ofeVideo FROM tbloferta WHERE ofeVideo is not null;
```